# How to set reference base on list item click in Angular through firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I'm a beginner in Angular. What I want is to update the list reference on list item click.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li  *ngFor="let chap of chapter | async">
    <button  class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light" (click)="getActiveId(chap.ChapterNo)" {{ chap.ChapterName | json }}</button>
  </li>
<ul>
```

This is code for list and action is

```
items: Observable<any[]>;

public getActiveId(id: number) {
  console.log(id);
  this.items = this.db.list('/Course/{{id}}').valueChanges();

 }
```

When I click on list item, the correct id is passed, seen through console but the reference of the list is not change.

Would you please tell me how to pass this id correctly so that the database list reference will be update

Comment: which reference?

Comment: Please post the definition of `this.db` variable.

Comment: public db: AngularFireDatabase @MichaelD

Comment: FireDatabase list reference @PeterHaddad

Comment: I'm not sure.. but try `this.items = this.db.list('/Course/'+id).valueChanges();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable [interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#interpolation-) using `{{...}}` is restricted to Angular HTML templates. To use a variable in the component, you could try one of the following

Option 1

```
this.items = this.db.list('/Course/' + id).valueChanges();
```

Option 2

```
this.items = this.db.list('/Course/', id).valueChanges();
```

Option 3

```
this.items = this.db.list(`/Course/${id}`).valueChanges();
```